# Cant understanding why to assign or convert a method to function object

Tags: scala

Going over a course in Scala. WhIle reading  functions, it says we can convert methods to a function object.

Like :

```
 val CalcCirclegetarea = getcircleArea (r: double)
```

Where `getcirclearea` is a method. 
Methods exist in a class. Functions are independent objects. I am trying think. Of situations  where a method has to be assigned to a function object.

Please believe me. I Googled before I am posting this.
Thanks

Comment: It's convenient when you want to pass a function to another function or a method as a parameter... something like `def m(f: Int => Int, y: Int) = f(y)`

Comment: Your question is unclear, and the code you pasted doesn't compile, and doesn't make sense. Please, clarify your question, and provide an actual working example of what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't pose an actual question. Is this what you're looking for?

```
def getcircleArea(r: Double) = math.Pi * r * r
val calcCirclegetarea = getcircleArea _
calcCirclegetarea(1)
```

The result of all this is, as expected, 3.14....

You might find my blog article helpful: [Functions vs. Methods in Scala](http://scalaprof.blogspot.com/2016/09/functions-vs-methods-in-scala.html).

Answer (score 0):

The most complete and understandable post about methods vs functions I ever read was this one: https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/06/09/methods-functions.html

hope it can help you